# Why is the gerund form is not possible after "would prefer"?

Tags: grammar

Why is the gerund form is not possible after "would prefer"? Most sites and books tell that "would prefer" is either followed by to infinitive or noun.

Examples from Cambridge:

> I’d prefer to go by myself.
> Would you prefer a quieter restaurant?
> She’d prefer not to drive at night.

On the other hand, I got some examples from the book (*New Interchange Teacher's Edition 3: English for International Communication* page 47). It also suggested using a gerund.

I think using a gerund is not wrong since the gerund itself = noun

One Example from the book:

> I would prefer singing in a choir to playing in an orchestra.

Moreover, the book tells that using the infinitive form is not possible with such example because of the presence of "to" a short form of compared "to"

Do I go with the information of the book or not ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  New Interchange book is correct:

- You can use a gerund after "would prefer". The example that the book gives ("I would prefer singing in a choir to playing in an orchestra") is grammatical and quite normal.
- You should not use this construction with a full infinitive:

  1. *"I would prefer to sing in a choir to playing in an orchestra." (lack of parallelism)
  2. *"I would prefer to sing in a choir to to play in an orchestra." (use of infinitive as object of a preposition)

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/146667/marcinmanhattan   Thank you very much